# C++ struct is destruct after the function returns

Tags: c++, visual-c++, direct2d

A bitmap struct I translate in another function is set to NULL after the function returns

the function :

```cpp
HRESULT RessourcesLoader::decode(LPCWSTR name,ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap1) {
    int hr = S_OK;
    hr = LoadFile(name, bitmap1);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = rendertarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(wicConverter, NULL, &bitmap1);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

return hr;
```

called here :

```cpp
ID2D1Bitmap* bmp1=NULL;
ID2D1Bitmap* bmp2=NULL;


rl->decode(L"Menu_corner.png", bmp1);

rl->decode(L"Menu_side.png", bmp2);
```

(inside the function hr is S_OK and the struct have all in it, once the function return the pointers are NULL)
is it a scope issue ?

Comment: If you want to get the pointer assignment out of `decode` function you must specify the function like `HRESULT RessourcesLoader::decode(LPCWSTR name,ID2D1Bitmap** bitmap1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that C++ parameters like `ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap1` are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).  That means you have two completely separate (and almost unrelated) variables `bmp1` and `bitmap1`.  The only relationship the two variables have is that `bitmap1` starts life with the same value that `bmp1` had when `decode` was called - i.e., `NULL`.

Your `decode` logic calls `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` passing in the address of `bitmap1`and `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` carefully fills `bitmap1` with the address of the newly created bitmap.  **But** that doesn't affect `bmp1` at all.  So `bmp1` remains set to null.  You can check this for yourself by placing a breakpoint on `return hr` and then looking at the contents of `bmp1` and `bitmap1`.

If you want Decode to change the contents of `bmp1` you need to pass the address of `bmp1` to `decode` not the contents.  That means bitmap1 should be type `ID2D1Bitmap **` and decode should be called like this... `rl->decode(L"Menu_corner.png", &bmp1);`

**Update**

Several comments pointed out that I was rather careless in saying "C++ parameters are passed by value", I've reworded the text above to be more focused.

The comments also point out that that C++ parameters can be passed by reference as well as by value.  In the case of the `decode` function by using the syntax `ID2D1Bitmap*& bitmap1`.

I have to confess I'm somewhat ambivalent about the relative merits of `ID2D1Bitmap** bitmap1` and `ID2D1Bitmap*& bitmap1`.  But that may say more about my personal biases than about anything else.

Comment: C++ has pass-by-reference natively, there's no reason to use the old C hack of simulating it with pass-by-pointer

Comment: *Remember that C++ parameters are passed by value.* -- This is true in `C`, not true in `C++`.  C++ has both pass by value and pass by reference, since reference types do not exist in `C`.

Comment: @M.M +1 for keeping me honest!  :-)   There's a tension between discussing what's wrong with the code as presented versus discussing alternative ways of achieving the intended outcome.  But yes, I got the balance wrong.  I should have mentioned reference variables somewhere in my answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Fair point.  I should have expressed myself more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a *copy* of your bitmap pointers to your function.  Your function modifies the copies, but that has no effect on the original pointers from which the copies were made.

If you want to modify the pointers you pass to your function, you need to pass either a reference or pointer to them:

```
HRESULT RessourcesLoader::decode(LPCWSTR name, ID2D1Bitmap*& bitmap1) {
                                                        // ^----- Pass by reference
    int hr = S_OK;
    hr = LoadFile(name, bitmap1);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = rendertarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(wicConverter, NULL, &bitmap1);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    return hr;
}
```